# numbers of directed spanning trees and undirected spanning trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a balanced directed graph. 'Balanced' means the in-degree equals to the out-degree at each vertex. It can be shown that the directed spanning trees always exist and the number of directed spanning trees is independent of the choice of the root vertex, so it makes sense to say the number of directed spanning trees of $G$.

My question is, does the same result hold for undirected spanning trees? If so, what's the relation between the number of directed spanning trees and the number of undirected spanning trees?

Comment: Please provide more details and references to existing results

Comment: @Amir You may find it in this paper: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0129167X21500737